# Sessions dropped intermittently in ColdFusion/IIS

Tags: session, iis, cookies, coldfusion

Several times per day (though we cannot reproduce it ourselves), we're seeing instances of sessions being dropped.

What I mean is I have logs of the user coming to the site, performing a few requests, and then having **each of their next few requests get a different session identifier** and thus wiping out everything in their session. Same IP, same browser, and all of this happens in the course of a couple seconds. The session timeout is configured to 20 minutes.

It doesn't appear to be related to a specific browser, as users have claimed coworkers don't experience the issue on the same machine.

What's really bizarre is that for some requests I can clearly see one session ID coming in through CGI.HTTP_COOKIE and another one is assigned during the course of the request (by the time we get an error email, which is caused by their lack of session). WTF?

To my knowledge, nothing in our application code could be causing this. We use session variables of course, but don't wipe or reset the session ID cookies. I was under the impression that's completely handled by the server.

I'm ripping my hair out here. Any ideas on even how to go about debugging this would be appreciated.